# How to add a library project to Android Studio online and offline both type?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I add a library project (such as Youtube Jar) to Android Studio?

(Not to the old ADT Eclipse-based bundle, but to the new Android Studio.)

i have one more question i if i have old version of youtube library in jar and i never want to update its affected to my future versionof android app or not.

Comment: Why are you even trying to put SherlockABS in your project? It is [deprecated](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) , and hasn't been updated in over 5 years

Comment: sorry for example like youtube jar

Comment: This should cover it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiuqMu5UHMQ

Comment: use repository dependency wherever possible instead of jar dependancy. Youtube for sure has a repository dependency available

Comment: i have one more question i if i have old version of youtube library in jar and i never want to update its affected to my future version or not.

Comment: it totally depends on the library itself, but likely it will stop being supported soon or later

Comment: ok i understand

Answer (score 1):

Inside your project's `app` folder, there is one directory named `libs` which is empty may be. You need to paste your `.jar` lib file inside that `libs` folder.

After then go to your app's `build.gradle` file. In it inside your `dependencies{}` block write this line of code.

Inside your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
 implementation files('libs/youtube_or_your_jar_file_name.jar')
}
```